# Using the distributive property to factor $(5^{-1}\cdot 5^x - 5^x - 5\cdot 5^x + 5^2\cdot 5^x)$

Tags: exponentiation, factoring

I can't seem to understand the distributive property.

Take this:

$$ 5^{-1}\cdot 5^x - 5^x - 5\cdot 5^x  + 5^2\cdot 5^x$$

becoming this:

$$ 5^x\left(\frac 15 - 1 - 5 +25\right) $$

Help? :D

Answer (score 1):

Every term has a factor of $5^x$ which is factored out.

Also, note that:

$$5^{-1} = \frac 1{5^1} = \frac 15,\quad 5^2 = 25$$

---

$$\begin{align}  5^{-1}\cdot \color{blue}{5^x} -  (1)\cdot \color{blue}{5^x} - 5\cdot \color{blue}{5^x} + 5^2\cdot \color{blue}{5^x} &= \frac 15\cdot \color{blue}{5^x} -(1)\cdot \color{blue}{5^x} - 5\cdot \color{blue}{5^x}+ 25\cdot \color{blue}{5^x}\\ \\ &  =\color{blue}{5^x}\left(\frac 15 -1-5 + 25\right)\\ \\ & = \frac{96}5\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks! I still don't get the -5 though. In the upper expression it's x5 so shouldn't it be positive below?

Comment: Because we are *subtracting* $5^x \times 5$. For example, in the following we will subtract $ac$ from $a$: $a - ac = a(1-c)$.

Answer (score 0):

The original expression has 4 parts separated by a "$+$" or "$-$".  Each of those terms can be divided by $5^x$ individually.

What is inside the parentheses in the 2nd part is what's left after dividing.

For example, $5^x/5^x=1$